# Handling invalid http request parameters API Restful

Tags: java, api, rest, httprequest, httpresponse

I created a program that communicates through http requests. I use Postman to send requests. When I make a registration, I invoke the API method. If this method throws some exceptions, I manage it with "HandlerMapping" which catches the exception and sends a personalized message about it.

**HandlerMapping class:**

```
@Provider
public class HandlerMapper implements ExceptionMapper<InputValidationException>{

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(InputValidationException exception) {
        return Response.status(exception.getStatus().getStatusCode(), exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

**InputValidationException:**

```
public class InputValidationException extends Exception{
    private String errorMessage;
    private Response.Status status;

    @JsonbCreator
    public InputValidationException (@JsonbProperty("message") String message, @JsonbProperty("status") Response.Status status) {
        this.errorMessage = "Invalid param entered: " + message;
        this.status = status;
    }
.........
}
```

Now when it throws an exception from the API method it works and a customer message is sent as I would like. But if I send a message with the wrong param (for example with the name null), a custom response error is not created as I do with the api method, but the default message is created with 500 Server Error. How can I make a general class to handle errors in a personalized way?

**Client Client**

```
public class Client {
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String city_of_birth;
    .... another parameters ....
        
    @JsonbCreator
    public Cliente(@JsonbProperty("surname") String surname, @JsonbProperty("name") String name, @JsonbProperty("city_of_birth") String city_of_birth) throws InputValidationException {
        paramValidation(surname, name, city_of_birth, ......... );
        this.surname= surname;
        this.name= name;
        this.city_of_birth= city_of_birth;
        .... another parameters ....     
    }

    private void paramValidation(String surname, String name, String city_of_birth) throws InputValidationException{
        if( surname == null || surname.isBlank() ){
            throw new InputValidationException("surname", Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        }
        .... other parameter controls ....
    }

}
```

**API class**

```
@Path("homeBanking/client/signup")
public class Registration {
    private DaoClient daoC = new DaoClient();

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createClient(Client client) throws InputValidationException {
        daoC.insert(client);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your context the solution is creating an **Exception Mapper** to convert the exception message into a JSON object, following this structure: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html/ExceptionHandling.html

Using the *Spring Framework*, you can use the `ControllerAdvice` to create your own error messages. See this article: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

I hope I've helped!

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. As you can see, I've already used a ** Exception Mapper ** to convert the exception.

Also, I had already seen Spring Framework, but I would like to use a different solution to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't see your question correctly. Reading it again, I thought that maybe the solution is to create a "super" exception that all of your exceptions extend. After that create a mapper only for this exception. Maybe inside of that, it could have a status error.